# How do I add text above and below an arrow using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I am trying to add text above and below an arrow, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this without creating two arrows on top of each other, which looks awkward.

What I currently have looks a bit like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 4cm, auto]
    \node (0) [state, initial] {$q_0$};
    \node (1) [state, right = of 0] {$q_1$};
    \node (2) [state, right = of 1] {$q_2$};

    \path [-stealth]
        (0) edge node {A} (1)
        (1) edge [loop above] node {B} (1)
        (1) edge node {sample text above arrow} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to be also able to add some `sample text below arrow` in that same edge betweeen `(1)` and `(2)`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Just put two nodes along the edge: `edge node {left of path} node [swap] {right of path}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you, I thought I had tried that before and it didn't work but I must have messed something up.

Comment: The Keroten MWE proposed is a lot far from the original question without MWE.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution (tested before your code) like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,0) node[midway,above] () {above};
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,0) node[midway,below] () {below};
        \draw[red,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,4) node[midway,above,sloped] () {above};
        \draw[red,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,4) node[midway,below,sloped] () {below};
        \draw[cyan,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0) arc (-180:0:2) node[pos=.25,below,sloped] () {below};
        \draw[cyan,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0) arc (-180:0:2) node[pos=.75,above,sloped] () {above};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: You can also consider this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,0)
        node[midway,above] {above}
        node[midway,below] {below};
    
        \draw[red,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0)--(5,4)
        node[midway,above,sloped] {above}
        node[midway,below,sloped] {below};
        
        \draw[cyan,-latex,line width=2pt] (1,0) arc (-180:0:2)
        node[midway,below,sloped] {below}
        node[midway,above,sloped] {above};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simple add another edge nodes with option `below` (see @
Qrrbrbirlbel comment) or use `quotes` library and write your MWE (Minimal Working Example)  as follows:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,  
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4cm, 
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, align=center}
                        ]
\node (0) [state, initial] {$q_0$};
\node (1) [state, right = of 0] {$q_1$};
\node (2) [state, right = of 1] {$q_2$};

\path[-Stealth]
        (0) edge["A"] (1)
        (1) edge[loop above, "B"] (1)
        (1) edge["sample text\\ above arrow", 
                 "sample text\\ below arrow" swap] (2); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Instead option `swap` you can shortly write `'`.

[image]